# Identity: curl of product of functions

Tags: vector-analysis

I found in [this material](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~lipeijun/math690_f11/notes/sec1.1.pdf) an identity that seems useful for me:

Suppose $\color{blue}{f}$ is a scalar function and $\color{blue}{u}$ is a vector function

$$\color{blue}{    \nabla \times (f\,u) =  f\nabla \times u - u \times \nabla f}$$

Now, for make it clear, supposes:
$$\color{blue}{\;f(x,y,z) = 2x+y}$$
$$\color{blue}{u(x,y,z) = x \hat x - 2y \hat y + z \hat z} $$ 
$$\color{blue}{ f(x,y,z)* u(z,y,z) = (2x^2 + xy) \hat x + (-2yx - 2y^2) \hat y + (2xz+yz) \hat z }$$

So
$$\color{blue}{\nabla \times (f\,u)  =  curl (f(x,y,z)* u(z,y,z))}$$
$$\color{blue}{u \times \nabla f  =   u \times grad(u) =  u \times [2,1,0]} $$

In the last expression above, $\color{blue}{\times}$ above is cross product.

However, $\color{blue}{f\nabla \times u\;}$ is  a big mistery for me

I know a "cousin" (directional derivative)
$$\color{blue}{f\nabla \cdot u = \partial f / \partial x \, u_x   + \partial f / \partial y \, u_y + \partial f / \partial z \, u_z}$$

So I could imagine:

$$\color{blue}{f\nabla \times u = \begin{bmatrix}\hat x&\hat y & \hat z\\ \partial f / \partial x&\partial f / \partial y&\partial f / \partial z\\u_x&u_y&u_z \end{bmatrix}}$$

Is it real or am I crazy?

**UPDATE**

With the [Arthur](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/15500/arthur) answer now I know the right  interpretation:

$\color{blue}{f\nabla \times u\;}$ is $\color{blue}{f(\nabla \times u)\;}$

I've made

$$\color{blue}{\;f(x,y,z) = 2x}$$
$$\color{blue}{u(x,y,z) = -y \hat x + y \hat x  + x \hat z} $$ 
$$\color{blue}{ f(x,y,z)* u(z,y,z) = (2xy) \hat x + (-2xy) \hat y + (2z^2) \hat z }$$

And it confers!

I also discover another reference [here](https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~rzwicky2/VC/vc-RZ.pdf), page 30, identity D. The only difference is that appears $\;\color{blue}{+ \nabla f  \times u \; }$ instead of $\;\color{blue}{- u \times \nabla f  }$

Comment: No, it's supposed to be $f*(\nabla\times u)$

Comment: Is there a reason all your math is in blue?

Comment: No special reason. Just because it's clearer for me to see..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $f\nabla\times u$ means $f\cdot (\nabla\times u)$. The $f$ and the $\nabla$ do not interact directly here, and there isn't really any such thing as $f\nabla$.

(Well, technically, you can *make* it a thing that behaves just as the above. But I see little reason to do that, as it just increases the number of symbols whose meaning one has to remember, and it doesn't give us anything substantial in return.)

Comment: Yes, you are right and the material of Purdue University is very confusing. I found another version: in  https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~rzwicky2/VC/vc-RZ.pdf  page 30 identity D. I check manually your way  and it confers. PS: I  corrected the above link that was wrong.

Comment: Well, many papers use  $f \nabla \cdot u$  as directional derivative so the author of Purdue university  should use  $f (\nabla \times U)$  instead of  $f \nabla \times U$. What do you think?